# Getting different output in python

Tags: python, dataset, google-colaboratory

I am trying to get a dataset_dict with column names "question', 'context' in python.
I tried to do this with a DataFrame and text document code shown below:

```
tfile_train_question = open('train_question.txt', 'a')
tfile_train_question.write(new_train['df'].to_string())
tfile_train_question.close()
tfile_train_context = open('train_context.txt', 'a')
tfile_train_context.write(new_train_df['context'].to_string())
tfile_train_context.close()
tfile_test_question = open('test_question.txt', 'a')
tfile_test_question.write(new_val_df['question'].to_string())
tfile_test_question.close()
tfile_test_context = open('test_context.txt', 'a')
tfile_test_context.write(new_val_df['context'].to_string())
tfile_test_context.close()
datasets = load_dataset('text', data_files={'train': ['train_question.txt','train_context.txt'], 'test': ['test_question.txt','test_context.txt']})
print(datasets)
```

The output of print(datasets) is:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['text'],
        num_rows: 148
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['text'],
        num_rows: 8
    })
})
```

I want the output to be:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['questions','context'],
        num_rows: 148
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['questions','context'],
        num_rows: 8
    })
})
```

where the questions and context refer to the txt documents I am not sure how to go about doing this?
I also have training DataFrame: new_train_df['question'], new_train_df['answer']- question and answering training dataframe
and testing dataframe: new_test_df['question', new_test_df['answer']- question and answer for the testing DataFrame
Instead of having one feature called text for training and testing I want to have two features for training and testing called question and context.
I am not sure how to go about doing this in python in Google Colab

Answer (score -1):

```py
def read_write(file, dataset):
    with open(file, 'a') as f:
        f.write(dataset.to_string())

files = ['train_question.txt', 'train_context.txt',
         'test_question.txt', 'test_context.txt']
datasets = [new_train['df'], new_train_df['context'],
            new_val_df['question'], new_val_df['context']]

for file, dataset in zip(files, datasets):
    read_write(file, dataset)

datasets = load_dataset(['questions', 'context'], data_files={
    'train': ['train_question.txt', 'train_context.txt'],
    'test': ['test_question.txt', 'test_context.txt']
    })

print(datasets)
```